# getting _SUCCESS file for hive script

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, workflow, hive, oozie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override hadoop’s mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs in oozie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017433/override-hadoops-mapreduce-fileoutputcommitter-marksuccessfuljobs-in-oozie)

i am trying to run a hive script from an oozie workflow. the "mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs" property has been set to true but he hive script overwrites it and hence, i dont get the success file. is there a way i can configure the same property in my hive script or any other way to overcome this situation?

```
<property>
<name>mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
```

in the job tracker, it says that the "mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs" property for hive is set to true but still no _success file is available in the final output location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible because hive overrides the OutputCommitter with it's own NullOutputCommitter. See dupe question here:

[Override hadoop's mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs in oozie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017433/override-hadoops-mapreduce-fileoutputcommitter-marksuccessfuljobs-in-oozie)